# create a all but one item loop to apply effects

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, foreach, except

I would like my swift code to make a kind of loop that all items follow except one stated by the user. So for example below, I listed 4 buttons and 1 objc functions linked with the buttons. In b1 hit I know I can just write

`b1.backgroundcolor =  blue and b2.backgroundcolor = green, b3.backgroundcolor = green`. Butt I wanted to see if I could do something like `[b1!,b2,b3].forEach{$0.backgroundcolor = .green.}`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var b1 = UIButton()
var b2 = UIButton()
var b3 = UIButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [b1,b3,b2].forEach{
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview($0)
        $0.backgroundColor = .blue
    }


    b1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(b1Hit), for: .touchUpInside)

}

@objc func b1Hit(){

    change all buttons background color to green except b1

}

}
```

Comment: Depending on how similar `b1`, `b2`, and `b3` are in their functionality, you can make one general function with a `sender` parameter (`buttonHit(sender: UIButton)`), and use the `sender` parameter to know  which of the 3 buttons was hit. From there, you can do your looping, whilst knowing which button to skip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1:  Use `for in` with `where` clause

Use a `for in` loop with a `where` clause to exclude the one you want to exclude:

```
// change all buttons background color to green except b1
for button in [b1, b2, b3] where button != b1 {
    button.backgroundColor = .green
}
```

---

### Option 2:  Use `Set` and `subtracting`

```
Set([b1, b2, b3]).subtracting([b1]).forEach {
    $0.backgroundColor = .green
}
```

**or**

```
for button in Set([b1, b2, b3]).subtracting([b1]) {
    button.backgroundColor = .green
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is tag the buttons and use conditional statement to identify which buttons to change colors for while looping through:

For example, if you had buttonArray that was [b1,b2,b3]

```
var buttonArray : [UIButton]!

b1.tag = 1
b2.tag = 2
b3.tag = 3

func b1Hit(sender: UIButton) {

   buttonArray.forEach {

     if $0.tag != sender.tag {

       //change color

     }

   }    

}
```